# Swift 2.0, closure = function()

Tags: ios, swift, function, closures, swift2

Hey I have a question that I cant seem to get it work

I have closure type

```
public typealias VoidCompletionHandler = ()->Void
```

Then I create a optional variable

```
var favouritePropertyStateHandler:VoidCompletionHandler?
```

Then I call it

```
self.favouriteCellStateHandler?()
```

All works good

```
self.propertyModel?.favouritePropertyStateHandler = { self.favouriteStateChanged() }
```

Woks perfectly with fucntion type

```
func favouriteStateChanged()->Void
```

But why cant I just

```
self.propertyModel?.favouritePropertyStateHandler = self.favouriteStateChanged()
```

Types match - both are ?

```
()->Void
```

The error I get is

```
Cannot assign a value of type 'Void' ('aka '()') to a value of type 'VoidCopletionHanlder?'
```

**Solved**

```
self.propertyModel?.favouritePropertyStateHandler = self.favouriteStateChanged
```

However that creates another problem, how do I not cause eternal retain cycle? if I want self to be weak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're assigning the result from `self.favouriteStateChanged()`, not the function itself. Try

```
self.propertyModel?.favouritePropertyStateHandler = self.favouriteStateChanged
```

instead.

Comment: one thing to follow up, what about infinite retain cycle problem if self should be weak?

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius - You could preface a closure with [unowned self] (such as with `{[unowned self] in self.favouriteStateChanged() }`) if your propertyModel will be deallocated before your enclosing class. That should break the cycle.

Comment: Yeah thats what I done, just that means I have to use it the old way

Comment: [unowned self] is not very safe is it? because it assumes that the object is not going to be deallocated? better to use [weak self]

Comment: @AndriusSteponavičius - [weak self] requires an optional value. [unowned self] is safe to use in situations where you know that the recipient of the closure will be deallocated before your enclosing class. That's a fairly common situation with closures like this, in my experience. Apple has a good discussion about this in the "Resolving Strong Reference Cycles for Closures" subsection of the Swift Programming Language book.